# Why am I getting an NPE error when using my custom listview adapter?

Tags: android, listadapter

This would be a lengthy question with lots of code in it so to those who would take time to read it Thank you so much!

So basically I have an application made using Eclipse. The MAIN ACTIVITY is extended as FragmentActivity, called MenuMain.java. This activity have three fragments defined in its xml. And the one I am having problems with is the third one.

What I want to do is when the user clicks a button on the middle fragment, it would add content into a custom listview which is the third fragment.

Here is my class for displaying the content on the middle fragment.

ImageFragment.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {

      ProgressDialog pDialog;
      private  int imageResourceId;
      private ArrayList<String> menu_id =  new ArrayList<String>();
      private ArrayList<String> menu_name =  new ArrayList<String>();
      private ArrayList<String> menu_description =  new ArrayList<String>();
      int page = 0;
      String orderQuantity = "";
      EditText quantity;
      ListView lv;
    public ImageFragment(int imageResource, ArrayList<String> mid, ArrayList<String> mname, ArrayList<String> mdesc, int pg) {
        this.imageResourceId = imageResource;    
        this.menu_id = mid;
        this.menu_name = mname;
        this.menu_description = mdesc;
        this.page = pg;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_menu, container, false);

        Button next = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button back = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.back);
        Button add = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add);

        quantity = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(imageResourceId);

        //Change ID on Layout
        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_id);
        id.setText(menu_id.get(page));

        //Change name on layout
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        name.setText(menu_name.get(page));

        //change description on layout
        TextView desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_description);
        desc.setText(menu_description.get(page));

        // set next page button listener
                next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if(page < menu_id.size()-1)
                        {
                            page++;
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Next", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            loadMenuItem(page);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are at the end of the page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
        // set back page button listener
                back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if(page != 0)
                        {
                            page--;
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Next", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            loadMenuItem(page);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are at the start of the page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                //set add to orderlist button listener
                add.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(quantity.getText().toString() != "" || quantity.getText().toString() != "0" || quantity.getText().toString() != "00"){
                            lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.orderListView);
                            new AddToList().execute("");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please put quantity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        return view;


}
    public void loadMenuItem(int pahina) {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        if (fm != null) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.menu_fragment, new ImageFragment(R.drawable.caesar_salad, menu_id, menu_name,menu_description, pahina));
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    class AddToList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ArrayList<DataArray> dataArray = new ArrayList<DataArray>();
        DataArray data = new DataArray();
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
             Log.d("Activity Context", getActivity().toString() + "");
             pDialog.setMessage("Adding to list. Please wait...");
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
             pDialog.setCancelable(false);
             pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) {

            data.setID(menu_id.get(page));
            data.setName(menu_name.get(page));
            data.setQuantity(quantity.getText().toString());
            dataArray.add(data);
            Log.d("Order Data ID: ", data.getID() + "");
            Log.d("Order Data Name: ", data.getName() + "");
            Log.d("Order Data Quantity: ", data.getQuantity() + "");
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), dataArray));
        }

    }

}
```

I get an error here when I call my custom adapter in this line `lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), dataArray));` which is on the onPostExecute()

I define my custom adapter like this

MyCustomAdapter.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<DataArray> orderData;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataArray> passed) {
        orderData = passed;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return orderData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return orderData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_order_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txtQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtID.setText(orderData.get(position).getID());
        holder.txtName.setText(orderData.get(position).getName());
        holder.txtQuantity.setText(orderData.get(position).getQuantity());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtID;
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtQuantity;
    }
}
```

And my custom variable DataArray.java is like this. I have no problems with DataArray though as it logs content so I am sure the NPE error does not refer to my use of this class

package com.thesis.menubook;

public class DataArray {

```
    private String menu_ID = "";
    private String menu_name = "";
    private String quantity = "";

    public void setID(String ID) {
     this.menu_ID = ID;
    }

    public String getID() {
     return menu_ID;
    }

    public void setName(String menu_name) {
     this.menu_name = menu_name;
    }

    public String getName() {
     return menu_name;
    }
    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
     this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public String getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

I think the problem is because of the `getActivity()` in this line `lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), dataArray));` on ImageFragment. I have tried:

```
getActivity().getApplicationCOntext()
getActivity().getBaseContext()
getActivity().getParent().getApplicationContext()
getActivity().getParent().getBaseContext()
```

to NO avail.

So how do I get around this?

Here are the other less important classes and xml files which you may need to analyze to help me.

OrderListFragment.java

```
package com.thesis.menubook;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class OrderListFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_order_list, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

activity_order_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderlist"
        android:layout_width="505dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="@string/orderlist"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/orderListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

custom_order_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#C20000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_menu_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/activity_main_large"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_category_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuCategory"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.14"
         layout="@layout/activity_menu_category" />

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/menu_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.MenuFragment"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="0.71"
         layout="@layout/activity_menu_fragment" />


     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/orderlist_fragment"
         android:name="com.thesis.menubook.OrderListFragment"
         android:layout_width="167dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/activity_order_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_menu.xml (the middle fragment content xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/caesar_salad"
    android:gravity="top|bottom|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_name" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/menu_name" 
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="#2f000000" android:textColor = "@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_id" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/menu_name" 
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu_name"
        android:background="#2f000000" android:textColor = "@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menu_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

       <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_description" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#2f000000"  
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" 
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:text ="@string/menu_description"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

    </TextView>

         <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/menu_price" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="#2f000000"  
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" 
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:text ="@string/menu_price"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/quantity" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/menu_description" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" 
        android:background="#2f000000" 
        android:text="@string/quantity" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textStyle="italic" 
        android:typeface="sans"/>


    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/quantity" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quantity" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quantity" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:background="@android:color/white" 
        android:ems="2" 
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:inputType="number">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/add" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:text="@string/add" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my LogCat

```
02-16 13:25:25.541: D/Order Data ID:(502): 001
02-16 13:25:25.541: D/Order Data Name:(502): Chicken
02-16 13:25:25.541: D/Order Data Quantity:(502): 8
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.thesis.menubook.ImageFragment$AddToList.onPostExecute(ImageFragment.java:182)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.thesis.menubook.ImageFragment$AddToList.onPostExecute(ImageFragment.java:1)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-16 13:25:25.865: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 13:25:26.587: D/dalvikvm(502): GC_CONCURRENT freed 126K, 7% free 7635K/8199K, paused 23ms+35ms
02-16 13:25:32.642: I/Process(502): Sending signal. PID: 502 SIG: 9
```

Comment: why are you setting the adapter in onPostExecute()..? Try to set the adapter inside onCreateView() of your fragment and call notifyDatasetChanged() on your adapter in onPostExcecute().

Comment: By fragment you mean ImageFragment,java?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe : problem is  `lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.orderListView);` line you are trying to find ListView in wrong layout ?

Comment: Well how do you refer to the listview on the other fragment?

Comment: yes. And one more thing. You should pass the results from doInBackground() method to the onPostExecute() method instead of using a global variable to store the results.

Comment: I am getting an error when I put notifyDatasetCHanged()

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe : try to get ListView reference from `activity_menu_main` or `activity_order_list` layout

Comment: Any ideas how I can possibly do that on a Fragment?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe : you will need to inflate `activity_menu_main` layout

Comment: I have the activity_menu_main layout inflated from the second previous activity and it called the MenuMain.java. From what I understand from what you are saying I need to re-inflate the activity_menu_main layout when ImageFragment is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish but it seems to me that your list view is actually null. If I'm not mistaken you only initialize it on the add button onclicklistener and use the view that is passed along to look for the list in its hierarchy. The onClickListener is passed the actual view that was clicked and, as far as I know, you can't have a list view as a child of that button view and so the findViewById method returns null. Either initialize the list view along with the buttons or make sure you get the proper parent view of the list in order to load it at the button click.

Comment: Okay I'll initialize the list along with the buttons. What do you think is the parent view?

Comment: You have no list on your middle fragment, so you'll only be able to find the list once the third fragment is attached. The best approach would be to have the third fragment load the necessary data while it is being created. You should pass whatever information you need from the second fragment to the third using the setAgurment() method call and have all of the data loaded from there.

Comment: So basically I may need to simultaneously load the second and third fragments?

Comment: Not really, you just need to pass all the arguments it needs to load the data when it is created.

Comment: I did what you suggested by passing the arguments to orderlistfragment.java. So I made it to accept arraylist arguments. But the problem now is it would accept the data and add to the list when you click the button but once you pick a new category which means re inflatingthe imagefragment it would also reinflate the orderlistfragment thereby making he list blank. Anyways thanks for your insight and help. Hope you'll help me out on the next question I post

Comment: You should always have your activity handle fragment transitions and any state shared between fragments. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more information.